# How to retrieve proxy password stored in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, proxy, passwords

In OS X you can retrieve the username and password for proxy using keychain function `SecKeychainFindInternetPassword`.

In iOS there are `CFNetworkCopySystemProxySettings` and `CFNetworkCopyProxiesForURL` but they only return proxy hostname and username, not the password.

How can I retrieve the proxy password stored in the user settings in iOS?

Comment: If anyone interested, it seems this is not possible in iOS, since this information is stored in the system's KeyChain, which can only be accessed by system.